# Need to add xml as XFA to a Jasper Report created pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, xfa

We have a requirement from the courts to submit PDFs in which there is embedded data in xml format. Such that the xml is in an XFA Form in the PDF.

We generate our PDF From Jasper Reports, then generate the xml that we want to add. The generated PDF from Jasper Reports does not have am XFA Form to start importing the xml into.

How do I get the PDF to have an XFA Form created in it so that I can then add the xml of the data to it?

Comment: XFA will be deprecated in PDF 2.0 (ISO-32000-2) to be released in 2017. JasperReports doesn't support XFA; AFAIK, PdfBox doesn't support XFA either. iText has XFA support in the sense that it allows you to insert an XFA stream into an existing template, and you can use XFA Worker to flatten that template. You can create an XFA template using Adobe LiveCycle Designer and fill this template with iText. You can't create an XFA template with JasperReports. I think you're using the wrong tools. BTW: iText is developing an alternative for XFA. You might want to contact us.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie I wish we could use non XFA, but it is out of our hands. I left an answer where I got an interactive PDF that I can pass our XML to and populate the form.

Comment: Can you give a link to the exact ruling forcing you to use XFA?

Comment: mkl, that isn't necessary. Basically, that is how the court system wants the PDF. They have already rejected our forms as just AcroForms, or even embedded/attached xml file. It HAS to be XFA, because that is all they accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @BrunoLowagie Unfortunately, the format/rules of what we can use is out of our hands. The PDF is defined by the US Courts. But a co-worker was able to get me a copy of the PDF from the US Courts system that is an "interactive" form that is XFA, so I was able to get the data into the form with all the great work that you guys have done with iText.

Using the following code. All gotten from your great book.

```
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
xfa.fillXfaForm(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlSchemaStream.toByteArray()));
```

For anyone reading this in the future. If you wanted to add XFA to your PDF via Java code, the ONLY current solution is Adobe LifeCycle which the app itself is ONLY available on Windows, and you have to install it to get the jar files to use. OH, wait, it gets even better, you include the client jar files into your application. Which means, yes you guessed it, you have to install a Server application and run it in JBoss, Weblogic or Websphere.

So in the end it will cost way too much money to setup, manage and maintain for something as stupid as adding an XFA form to your PDF.